# Buying a car in Ireland as a non-resident

Tags: car-rentals, automobiles, ireland

Does anyone know how to buy a used car in Ireland as a  non-resident? I am Australian and looking to buy one for the Mongol Rally.  Insurance can be done, but it seems to register the car you need to go in to an office with proof of address. Is that correct? Is there anyway to give an address but we don't have to live there (eg, a friends)?

Comment: "Proof of address" always means "proof that you live at the given address." Proof that your friend lives there would be meaningless, unless they are the one who registers the car. Have you investigated whether the address has to be in Ireland?

Comment: Of course, it's an export. You register the car in your home country, a lot of paper works on the border, and it's highly dubious if it is worth an effort. You'd better go to company specialized in importing used cars.